# Can I log a user in with post request rather than through Laravel login page by default

Tags: php, json, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

In Laravel (5.4) I can login by going to `{domain}/login` and submitting the login form. This works fine.

What I want though, is to be able to send a request like so:

`{domain}/login?email=admin@example.com&password=pass1234`

and if user is authenticated, a json response would return with the api_token for that specific user, but if the user is rejected, a json response with the message "User login failed".

Is it possible to do this in Laravel as of yet? Or do I have to implement my own method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You'll have to modify your LoginController by adding a new method, along the lines of:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return json_encode($my_things);
        }
    }
```

You can read more at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authenticating-users